# Package path error when trying to install lib package in C

Tags: c, fedora, pkg-config

I am trying to install libpackedobjects on my fedora 17. The path that I am trying to install it on is home/libpackedobjects. The steps that I am following are:

1. `git clone git://gitorious.org/libpackedobjectsd/libpackedobjectsd.git`
2. `cd libpackedobjectsd`
3. `autoreconf -i`
4. `./configure`

when I am trying to run the `./configure` I am getting error:

```
checking for LIBPACKEDOBJECTS... no
configure: error: Package requirements (libpackedobjects) were not met:

No package 'libpackedobjects' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables LIBPACKEDOBJECTS_CFLAGS
and LIBPACKEDOBJECTS_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

I do understand that the path can not be found, but do not know how to repair the problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: It looks that there are two projects: libpackedobjectsd and libpackedobjects, and the first one depends on the second project to be built.

Comment: @Xeor can you run it on your machine or you are getting the same error?

Answer (score 1):

As evident from your error report:

```
checking for LIBPACKEDOBJECTS... no
configure: error: Package requirements (libpackedobjects) were not met:

No package 'libpackedobjects' found
```

Hence, You have to install the packages `libpackedobjects` and `libXml2`to install the `libpackedobjectsd`.
If you still get this error after installing the depenedent packages, there might be a PATH issue or linking issue.